# Chakra-UI removing default background color

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, chakra-ui

I'm using @chakra-ui/react with Tailwind CSS and NextJS. I have set my background color to `black` in my `globals.css` file:

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}
```

But I don't see the black color being applied, I only see a white screen. This worked before I switched to chakra so I suppose this is something to do with it.

This is my app.js file:

```js
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css'
import '../styles/globals.css' // file which sets the body's background-color to black

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

I assume this is because of chakra's default theme? How would I disable it?

Comment: For my use-case, I just imported a single component (that uses Chakra) into my existing app (which doesn't). It seems like I can't stop Chakra from going "out of bounds" of that component and changing ~everything. It's infuriating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this issue is being faced by anyone else, you can set the bg to an empty string in the extendTheme options:

```js
const theme = extendTheme({
  styles: {
    global: () => ({
      body: {
        bg: "",
      },
    }),
  },
});
```

This occurs when you use chakra's default theme, which sets the `style` of the `body-bg` to global: https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/78d9c30e6b9477080c75b2e601394a21ed93fcf2/packages/theme/src/styles.ts#L8

For more info, check this discussion: https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/discussions/4926

Comment: Still not working here, I also have a NextJS application using TailwindCSS and ChakraUI. When I switch the mode from white to dark, only my anchors change the colors to white, but the background keeps white (what should be gray.800)

Comment: worked for me when i wrote "background" instead of "bg"